# corrupted index in BinaryObject Cache ignite

Tags: ignite

I had critical problem and need all your help.
Our ignite cluster with 5 nodes have faced problem with corrupted index, It happended frequently, cannot restart Node. Here's our logs

> [23:10:36,093][SEVERE][rebalance-#553][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.tree.CorruptedTreeException: B+Tree is corrupted [groupId=1342847862, pageIds=[844420635281823], cacheId=1342847862, cacheName=InsExamsCache, indexName=_key_PK, msg=Runtime failure on row: Row@75e865f5[ key: InsExamsCacheKey [idHash=302918091, hash=525411351, order=1176621611, ID=1232911539], val: InsExamsCacheValue [idHash=1247370454, hash=-299407229

Comment: There should be a stack trace in the log, not only a message from the failure handler, could you please share it?

Answer (score 0):

Two parts.

1. Delete the `index.bin` file in the `InsExamsCache` folder, inside your persistent files folder. Then re-start your node. It will re-build the index automatically
2. If this is happening regularly, you should investigate why — I think it’s fair to say that most Ignite users never see this error. Old version of Ignite? Unreliable disks?

Comment: I had already deleted index.bin then restart, and it work for most corrupted index case, but sometime the corrupted index is  _key_PK index , so this method seem did't useful. Our ignite now is lastest version (2.15), my concern is why index was regularly corrupted, it only happended when used put api cache and cache was binaryObject key,value

Comment: As Vladimir says, you'd need to provide more information. Most likely you're inserting values of the wrong type. You have to be very careful directly using binary objects as you don't get the type checking you do when you use POJOs.